# How to get data from Intent or SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a weather app in Android Studio and I've a problem. When the user closes the app, I want to save the last city searched, and I used SharedPreferences for this.
If the user wants to search a new city, I have a "search button" that starts a new activity, where the user can choose another city and with an Intent  put the string in the MainActivity.

The problem is to check (at the start of the app) if a SharedPreferences exists(and get old data from this) or intent is != null (and get new data from this).
This is my code in "OnCreate" method. It works on emulator but not on my smartphone:

```
    value = ""; //this is a String
    
    pref = getSharedPreferences("meteo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    receive_from_intent = getIntent(); //This intent gets from "SearchActivity".

    add_city.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //this is the search button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent start_new = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(start_new);
        }
    });

    if (receive_from_intent.getExtras() != null) {
        value = receive_from_intent.getStringExtra("luogo"); //if it's a string you stored.
        //luogo means "city"
        if (!value.matches("")) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("luogo", value);
            editor.apply();
        }

        url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + value + ",it&mode=json&lang=it&units=metric&APPID=e8cff7ac36757b1ea60b460f036140df";
        url2 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + value + ",it&mode=json&lang=it&units=metric&APPID=e8cff7ac36757b1ea60b460f036140df";

        CercaLuogo(url, url2);

    } else if (pref.contains("luogo")) {

        value = pref.getString("luogo", "");

        url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + value + ",it&mode=json&lang=it&units=metric&APPID=e8cff7ac36757b1ea60b460f036140df";
        url2 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + value + ",it&mode=json&lang=it&units=metric&APPID=e8cff7ac36757b1ea60b460f036140df";
        CercaLuogo(url, url2);

    } else Toast.makeText(this, "Click on search button and insert new city.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Well what does not work exactly? Should we guess?

Comment: @blackapps I don't know exactly. On the Android Studio emulator it works fine, I have no errors. On my smartphone, the app crashes since the second start..

Comment: Then post the relevant lines from the lgcat. It tells you all.